# Dynamically generated css not loading in details page in umbraco

Tags: css, html, umbraco

hello i am in a fix on what to do with my current situation.

I am trying to implement an html5 blog template with Umbraco. My template loads the css files with the help of jquery for the sake of responsive design.

Now this is okay for the home page as all the files are placed at the root of the site.

But whenever I click on a particular blogpost, the css files are not correctly retrieved because of the folder structure. A blogpost is placed in a datefolder directory as you already know.

I cant explicitly include the css files as all the files are not loaded at once. They are loaded one at a time depending on the browser window size.

Please give me some directions about which way to go. Ask me if you need more details.

Comment: Do you have any code samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `base` tag to define the base URL for all linking attributes, e.g. href, src

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.site.com" />
</head>
```

Even if this does not work exactly as intended in loading your CSS dynamically, you could use jQuery to pull the `base` tag's `href` value out to prepend the CSS file location.

You can of course make the href value editable via the CMS if required.